# Query Optimization for multiple query joined by union

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find a way to enhance my SQL Query. Can someone recommend me the best possible way to optimize this query. In short I want to make it faster. This query is used to count the number of people currently inside the grandstand per **up to this HOUR** basis. I have to get the **max LogDatetime** of each ticket until that hour and then join it to the base view so I could get the **Log Information (Log Location and Log Type)**.
LogType = 1 is Checkin tickets, 0 = Checkout.

This is the Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fld.Grandstand,log9h.LogHour,Count(log9h.TicketNo) AS TotalOccupancy
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT TicketNo, logDay,9 as Loghour, MAX(LogDateTime) AS LastLog
       FROM          dbo.viewF1LogDetail
        WHERE LogDay = 14 AND LogHour < = 9
       GROUP BY TicketNo, logDay
) AS log9h 
INNER JOIN dbo.viewF1LogDetail AS fld ON fld.TicketNo = log9h.TicketNo 
                            AND fld.LogDateTime = log9h.LastLog
WHERE (fld.ScanningLogLocationType =('Grandstand')) AND (fld.LogType = 1)
GROUP BY fld.Grandstand,log9h.LogHour

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT fld.Grandstand,log10h.LogHour,Count(log10h.TicketNo) AS TotalOccupancy
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT TicketNo, logDay,10 as Loghour, MAX(LogDateTime) AS LastLog
       FROM          dbo.viewF1LogDetail
        WHERE LogDay = 14 AND LogHour < = 10
       GROUP BY TicketNo, logDay
) AS log10h 
INNER JOIN dbo.viewF1LogDetail AS fld ON fld.TicketNo = log10h.TicketNo 
                            AND fld.LogDateTime = log10h.LastLog
WHERE (fld.ScanningLogLocationType =('Grandstand')) AND (fld.LogType = 1)
GROUP BY fld.Grandstand,log10h.LogHour

UNION


SELECT DISTINCT fld.Grandstand,log11h.LogHour,Count(log11h.TicketNo) AS TotalOccupancy
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT TicketNo, logDay,11 as Loghour, MAX(LogDateTime) AS LastLog
       FROM          dbo.viewF1LogDetail
        WHERE LogDay = 14 AND LogHour < = 11
       GROUP BY TicketNo, logDay
) AS log11h 
INNER JOIN dbo.viewF1LogDetail AS fld ON fld.TicketNo = log11h.TicketNo 
                            AND fld.LogDateTime = log11h.LastLog
WHERE (fld.ScanningLogLocationType =('Grandstand')) AND (fld.LogType = 1)
GROUP BY fld.Grandstand,log11h.LogHour

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT fld.Grandstand,log12h.LogHour,Count(log12h.TicketNo) AS TotalOccupancy
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT TicketNo, logDay,12 as Loghour, MAX(LogDateTime) AS LastLog
       FROM          dbo.viewF1LogDetail
        WHERE LogDay = 14 AND LogHour < = 12
       GROUP BY TicketNo, logDay
) AS log12h 
INNER JOIN dbo.viewF1LogDetail AS fld ON fld.TicketNo = log12h.TicketNo 
                            AND fld.LogDateTime = log12h.LastLog
WHERE (fld.ScanningLogLocationType =('Grandstand')) AND (fld.LogType = 1)
GROUP BY fld.Grandstand,log12h.LogHour

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT fld.Grandstand,log13h.LogHour,Count(log13h.TicketNo) AS TotalOccupancy
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT TicketNo, logDay,13 as Loghour, MAX(LogDateTime) AS LastLog
       FROM          dbo.viewF1LogDetail
        WHERE LogDay = 14 AND LogHour < = 13
       GROUP BY TicketNo, logDay
) AS log13h 
INNER JOIN dbo.viewF1LogDetail AS fld ON fld.TicketNo = log13h.TicketNo 
                            AND fld.LogDateTime = log13h.LastLog
WHERE (fld.ScanningLogLocationType =('Grandstand')) AND (fld.LogType = 1)
GROUP BY fld.Grandstand,log13h.LogHour


UNION

SELECT DISTINCT fld.Grandstand,log14h.LogHour,Count(log14h.TicketNo) AS TotalOccupancy
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT TicketNo, logDay,14 as Loghour, MAX(LogDateTime) AS LastLog
       FROM          dbo.viewF1LogDetail
        WHERE LogDay = 14 AND LogHour < = 14
       GROUP BY TicketNo, logDay
) AS log14h 
INNER JOIN dbo.viewF1LogDetail AS fld ON fld.TicketNo = log14h.TicketNo 
                            AND fld.LogDateTime = log14h.LastLog
WHERE (fld.ScanningLogLocationType =('Grandstand')) AND (fld.LogType = 1)
GROUP BY fld.Grandstand,log14h.LogHour

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT fld.Grandstand,log15h.LogHour,Count(log15h.TicketNo) AS TotalOccupancy
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT TicketNo, logDay,15 as Loghour, MAX(LogDateTime) AS LastLog
       FROM          dbo.viewF1LogDetail
        WHERE LogDay = 14 AND LogHour < = 15
       GROUP BY TicketNo, logDay
) AS log15h 
INNER JOIN dbo.viewF1LogDetail AS fld ON fld.TicketNo = log15h.TicketNo 
                            AND fld.LogDateTime = log15h.LastLog
WHERE (fld.ScanningLogLocationType =('Grandstand')) AND (fld.LogType = 1)
GROUP BY fld.Grandstand,log15h.LogHour

ORDER BY Grandstand,Loghour
```

Sample Data:

```
Grandstand  LogHour TotalOccupancy
Main    11  11
Main    12  15
Main    13  12
Main    14  14
Main    15  22
Main    16  25
Main    17  31
Main    18  22
Main    19  11
West    10  2
West    11  22
West    12  23
West    13  24
West    14  55
West    15  56
West    16  57
West    17  22
West    18  23
West    19  11
South   10  22
South   11  21
South   12  26
South   13  55
South   14  56
South   15  78
South   16  99
South   17  22
South   18  11
South   19  1
```

Not a convincing query right? Thanks in advance for your recommendations.

Comment: So there's nothing wrong, except you want it to be faster? You should try posting here: [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: BTW, you want more people to work on this, make it easy for them to help out. Add a script to generate the tables and some sample data. I usually jump all over those because the person asking the question shows they are serious about wanting help, not just getting someone else to do thier work for them.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing some sample rows and expected results it's a little difficult to understand the question.  Would this work?

```
SELECT      Grandstand,
            LogHour,
            COUNT(TicketNo) AS TotalOccupancy
FROM        dbo.viewF1LogDetail
WHERE       LogDay = 14
            AND ScanningLogLocationType = 'Grandstand'
            AND LogType = 1
            AND LogHour >= 9
            AND LogHour <= 15
GROUP BY    Grandstand,
            LogHour;
```

If this doesn't work, an explanation of why would probably reveal the real intention of the query.

UPDATE:

I think I understand a bit better now.  Try this:

```
WITH hourRows AS
(   /* Get a base set of hours in the day */
    SELECT  TOP (24) 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) hr
    FROM    sys.objects
), ticketInfo AS (
    /* Return the check in log event */
    SELECT      ld1.Grandstand,
                ld1.LogHour AS CheckInHour,
                checkout.LogHour AS CheckOutHour,
                ld1.TicketNo
    FROM        viewF1LogDetail ld1
                CROSS APPLY ( /* Apply the check out time to the set */
                    SELECT      ld2.LogHour
                    FROM        viewF1LogDetail ld2
                    WHERE       ld2.LogDay = 14
                                AND ld2.ScanningLogLocationType = 'Grandstand'
                                AND ld2.LogType = 0
                                AND ld2.LogHour >= 9
                                AND ld2.LogHour <= 15
                                AND ld1.Grandstand = ld2.Grandstand
                                AND ld1.TicketNo = ld2.TicketNo
                ) checkout
    WHERE       ld1.LogDay = 14
                AND ld1.ScanningLogLocationType = 'Grandstand'
                AND ld1.LogType = 1
                AND ld1.LogHour >= 9
                AND ld1.LogHour <= 15
)
SELECT      ci.GrandStand,
            hr.hr AS LogHour,
            COUNT(ci.TicketNo) AS TotalOccupancy
FROM        hourRows hr
            INNER JOIN ticketInfo ci ON    hr.hr >= ci.CheckInHour 
                                                AND hr.hr <= ci.CheckOutHour 
GROUP BY    ci.GrandStand,
            hr.hr
ORDER BY    ci.Grandstand;
```

Note that you should replace sys.objects in the hourRows CTE with a real Numbers table.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this does hourly change rather than aggregate up to the hour.

Comment: Hi I added some sample rows now. This query will not work for me because this will only count all the check in made by the ticket.   what I need is to get the status of a ticket until a given log hour. let say ticket 001 is at main grandstand until 14th hour but has left at 15th hour. so at 14th hour he will be included in the total occupancy count but will not be included in the count by 15th hour because he has already left the main grandstand.

Comment: See if the new query I added is better.

Comment: Hi @JonBoulineau, your query have a good concept but it took a longer time to run than my previous query. It is a very organized query though. thanks for giving new ideas.